# Sorting upload images with jQuery UI sortable and save to database

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

```
<input type="file" name="uploadPhotos[]" class="upload" multiple accept='image/*' />
<div class="previewBlock" id="sortable"></div>
```

I build preview upload images with js

```
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files;
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
        if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
            continue;
        }
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (function (theFile) {
            return function (e) {
                $('.previewBlock').append(
                    $('<div/>').append(
                        $('<div/>').append(
                            $('<img/>').attr({
                                name: theFile.name,
                                src: e.target.result,
                                title: escape(theFile.name)
                            }).append(escape(theFile.name))
                        )
                    )
                );
            };
        })(f);
        reader.readAsDataURL(f);
    }
}
$('.upload').change(handleFileSelect);
```

I work with $_FILES and save images to DB by default sorting.
How can i send re-sorting array with upload images to PHP after jQuery UI sorting?

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
        start: function(event, ui) { },
        change: function(event, ui) { },
        update: function(event, ui) {
            //
        }
$('#sortable').disableSelection();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could handle this with an [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) request.

```
update: function(event, ui) {

    var images = "array of ids or something"

    $.ajax({
        url: '/path/to/php/file',
        type: 'POST',
        data: images,
        success: function( response ) {
            console.log( response );
        }
    });

}
```

on the PHP side, you just need something to handle the request and return a response.

Comment: Thanks for reply.
If i want to send images and they sorting with other form fields in one post, can i not use temporary table (or etc.) and save sorting actions on client?